# Partial class methods/properties not visible from another project

Tags: c#, .net, partial-classes

I have a Entity class (auto-generated) that looks like this:

```
namespace FicServerData
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Snapshot
    {
        public Snapshot()
        {
            this.ComponentQuotes = new HashSet<SnapshotPart>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Machine { get; set; }
        public string AppName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SnapshotPart> ComponentQuotes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a utility partial class to looks like this:

```
namespace FicServerData
{
    public partial class Snapshot
    {
        public IEnumerable<Quote> DerivedQuotes
        {
            get
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So those are both files in the same project and as you can see in the same namespace. Now inside this project I can access the property i added no problem. I can't access it from a project that references it though: i only have access to the Entity class VS has created for me.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access partial classes across projects. The 'parts' of partial classes are compiled to a single class within a single assembly.

Comment: If it compiles into the one class, shouldn't all method/props be visible?

Comment: This was some kind of strange VS behaviour. After rebuilding everything a few times suddenly it works okay. Bizarre.

Comment: @JarekMitek I think your DLL was just failing to build before and you where getting a old copy of it from before you added your partal class of your own.

Answer (score 2):

The fix for me was to restart the Visual Studio. I am at version Professional 2017.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I found that my consuming project was referencing the source project via an assembly reference rather than a project reference. Further, the assembly being referenced was stored in a drive folder, and that drive folder was added as a reference path in the consuming project. As you would expect, my updates in the source project were compiling, but my referenced assembly was not. I deleted the reference in my consuming project and re-added it as a project reference, et voila! Problem solved!

Don't ask me why my consuming project was using a refence path to access a compiled assembly from another project in the same solution. Please, don't.